# cURL from a gamecast

Tags: html, curl, web

Im wondering if there is anyway to get scores from a gamecast that uses javascript or flash to update the content dynamically.  Here's an example: http://www.cstv.com/gametracker/launch/gt_wlacros.html?sport=wlacros&camefrom=&startschool=md&event=952412&school=cs&
How could I pull the scores from the teams out of this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really what you need to do is sniff the requests being made under the hood. You can get any sort of HTTP sniffer. I use [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) extension for firefox. You start capturing, then click the link above. You'll see all sorts of requests. The underlying data seems to be coming from http://origin.livestats.www.cstv.com. I got this request that has a lot of useful player stats from the game:

http://origin.livestats.www.cstv.com/livestats/data/w-lacros/952412/player_stats.xml?344026907808

http://origin.livestats.www.cstv.com/livestats/data/w-lacros/952412/summary.xml?644493847800
(note the second url throws an XML parse error, but you could still try to parse it manually)

Comment: this is great thank you.  Is there anyway to use python or curl to see what xml page the webpage is requesting for data?

Comment: @KaiserWilhelm It would be exceedingly difficult. You would have to embed a browser or hack a flash plugin. The XML page is fetched from the flash code, so it's not possible to know ahead of time. You would have to actually run the flash app somehow.